# How to represent a variable vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

For formulating a potential energy minimization problem, I need a mathematical representation to a variable orientation vector. The problem in simplified form can be elaborated as follows.

The unit vector (say P) is such that its tail is fixed at origin and head can acquire any position on X-Y, Y-Z and Z-X planes. In other words, head can take any position on the circumferences of three circles x^2 + y^2 = 1, z^2 + y^2 = 1 and x^2 + z^2 = 1. Now I have to minimize the dot product P.E (say E = (E1, E2, E3))to find the orientation of P. But, I do not know how to put P in equation form. Will appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shall represent the unit vector into polar form, i.e. in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

There are different conventions as to which angles are used.
Taking the *Physics* convention:

$( \sin \theta \cos \phi , \, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \, \cos \theta) \; | \, 0 \le \theta \le \pi, \,  0 \le \phi < 2 \pi $

Comment: sure. but again, how to represent it ?

Comment: Thanks. I though of it earlier, but was not sure how to constrain (theta, phi) values such that head of the vector remains on the three mutually perpendicular circles, while I perform the minimization calculations of the dot product of it with another vector.